# Некорректно выводится строка в процедуре

Tags: c, строки

Программа переводит число из троичной системы счисления в десятичную. Не понимаю, почему printf в void неправильно работает. Вроде бы строка успешно считывается, а сам num высчитывается неверно. Буду признателен за помощь.

```
void three(char* s) {
    int num = 0;
    char result[9];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        int digit = s[i] - '0';
        num += digit * pow(3, strlen(s) - i - 1);
    }
    sprintf(result, "%d", num);
    printf("%s", result);
}


int main() {
    char str[9];
    fgets(str,9,stdin);
    three(str);
}
```

Comment: Что вводите? Что получаете на выходе?

Comment: Возможно, ввод вы заканчиваете нажатием на Enter, что добавляет символ новой строки в поток ввода, а функция `fgets` пишет этот символ в массив `str`. В дальнейшем этот символ интерпретируется как цифра, т.е. как часть троичного числа, что является ошибкой. Попробуйте считывать входную строку так: `scanf(" %8s", str);`. Пробел после кавычки, чтобы игнорировать ведущие пробельные символы, если таковые имеются. Пробельные символы после цифр будут игнорироваться автоматически. `8` — это максимальное кол-во считываемых символов, после которых в массив `str` также будет добавлен нулевой символ.

Comment: Также не следует использовать функцию `pow` в целочисленных вычислениях, т.к. вызов `pow(3, 2)` запросто может вернуть что-то наподобие `8.99....`, что в дальнейшем исказит итоговый результат. Можно, например, перебирать массив троичных цифр справа налево, и на каждой итерации цикла вычислять очередную степень как произведение предыдущей степени и тройки. Или вообще определить заранее предвычисленный массив степеней и брать значения из него.

Comment: @wololo, также не следует писать ответы в комментариях ;)

Comment: `Пробел после кавычки, чтобы игнорировать ведущие пробельные символы, если таковые имеются.` Пардон, для спецификатора преобразования `%s` это не требуется. Можно просто `"%8s"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) читает строку вместе с переводом строки. Если вы читаете 1212, то получаете такие коды символов в строке `s`:

> ```
> символы '1'  '2'  '1'  '2' '\n' '\0'
> коды     49   50   49   50  10   0
> цифры    1    2    1    2  -38
> ```

Последняя цифра со странным значением `-38` портит результат.

Поменяйте способ чтения данных чтобы исключить перевод строки. Лучше читать не строку, в которую могут попасть пробелы и в которую попадает перевод строки, а слово до следующего пробельного символа. Замените `fgets(str,9,stdin);` на `scanf("%8s", str);`.

**P.S.**

- Если читаете в фиксированный буфер, то берите буфер с запасом. Девять символов мало, сто символов - нормально.
- `strlen` в условии цикла - плохо. Он вычисляется в каждой итерации цикла, и вычисляется проходом по всей строке.
- Не нужно использовать `pow` в этой задаче. Она не обязана считать степени точно для целочисленных аргументов. Небольшая ошибка приведёт к неправильному чтению числа.
- Обычный способ решить задачу - считать цифры со старших, умножая предыдущий накопленный результат на три. Точная целочисленная арифметика:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned parse(const char *s) {
    unsigned n = 0;
    for (const char *p = s; *p != '\0'; ++p) {
        n = 3 * n + (unsigned)(*p - '0');
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {
    char s[100];
    while (scanf("%99s", s) == 1) {
        printf("%u\n", parse(s));
    }
}
```